# Cosmetic items unequipping from loadout

Tags: team-fortress-2

Ever since they removed the set loadout of Hat/Misc/Misc to Whatever/Whatever/Whatever, mostly cosmetics have been disappearing from my loadout when I play the game.

Is there any fix for this? It's a recurring issue, and I've had friends who've experienced the same thing.

Comment: should be a bug

Comment: Does un-equpipping and re-equipping the items have any effect?

Comment: When several people have experienced the same behavior (I've experienced it, as well), you can safely attribute it to general bugginess. There isn't anything to be done except hope Valve fixes the code.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this problem persists to you to this date, but for completeness purposes:

A teammate of mine having this problem found out that Items tend to not unequip themselves when you don't put them into Loadout slot A, but slots B-D instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Steam items server is down when you play. Try restarting Steam, that works for me whenever I get inventory problems. Hope I could help!

Comment: That's not possible, because I'm able to see all my hats in game and change loadout, it's just they're dissapearing between rounds, and I have to re-equip them.